# WordPress plugin is not work properly

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress plugin that has always worked OK in the past suddenly isn’t working, why do this type of error in wordpress?

Comment: This is not a question. What plugin? What Wordpress version? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Make sure that you’ve downloaded the latest version of the plugin`. New releases of plugins add features, but they also often fix bugs, including the one you might be having.

To check for new versions of your plugins, just click Administration and Plugin. WordPress should list all of your plugins, along with notifications of any that have upgrades available. `Click Upgrade Automatically, and you’ll have the latest version.` (In fact, checking for the latest versions of all of your plugins is something you probably should do on a regular basis, perhaps two to four times per year.)

If that doesn’t work, you have a few other options. You can try reinstalling the plugin from scratch; perhaps the plugin software became corrupted. Try to remember if you made any other software changes or installed other plugins between the time the problematic plugin was working correctly and the time that it failed.

You could have an incompatibility issue between the malfunctioning plugin and the software changes you made. `See if the author of the plugin has a blog where you can report your problem`. It’s possible others are having the same issue, and the plugin author will create a fix or knows a workaround.

Occasionally, `if you upgrade your version of WordPress, you could end up with multiple plugins that stop working correctly`. You’ll just have to deactivate the malfunctioning plugins until the author comes up with a new release that will be compatible with the new version of WordPress.

if you want more details click here. [Link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably upgraded your Wordpress version and the plugin is no longer compatible. Another possibility is that you've installed a conflicting plugin or changed some settings. You could also have used the plugin incorrectly inadvertently.

It would help if you explained what plugin you're using, what error you're getting, and what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If a wordpress plugin stops working it could be for a number of reasons:

- It was relying on a web service which no longer exists/returns and is not handling this case gracefully
- Someone has upgraded to the latest version which no longer plays nice with the version of WP you're running or the version of PHP you have installed.
- Another plugin that you have installed is now conflicting with the plugin.

Have you enabled wp-debug in the wp-config file?

Answer (score 0):

if you plugin stop working first question you have to ask yourself is:

1.- Did I install another plugin so it's having conflict with jquery (for example)
2.- Did I recently upgraded WordPress. (perhaps that plugin doesn't work with the new version)

and then you could have more answers depending on which plugin is.